# Implementing atoi() in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel

I was given a school assignment to implement `atoi()`. Please review my code.

```
int my_atoi(char *ato)
{
    int res;
    int sign;

    res = 0;
    sign = 1;
    while (*ato == ' ' || *ato == '\t' || *ato == '\n' || *ato == '\f' || *ato == '\r')
        ato++;
    if (*ato == '-')
        sign = -1;
    if (*ato == '-' || *ato == '+')
         ato++;
    while (*ato >= '0' && *ato <= '9')
    {
        res = res * 10 + *ato - '0';
        ato++;
    }
    return (sign * res);
}
```

Comment: You should probably show us your test suite too - the overflow bugs in this code suggest that you are missing the tests for very large (positive or negative) values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Be consistent with `stdlib.h` declaration of `atoi()`

The standard declaration is `int atoi(const char *str);`. Your declaration should match (i.e., take a `const char *` instead of `char *`).

### What happens if a NULL pointer is passed?

As written, you dereference `ato` without checking if it is NULL (0). <s>That is a big no-no in C. At the very top of the function, you should check if it's 0 and return 0 if it is:</s>

```
if (!ato) { return 0; }
```

**Edit**: Martin R points out that silently returning 0 when a NULL pointer is passed to your function, as I have suggested, is *bad programming practice*, because it hides the error. If there's a possibility of calling `myatoi()` with a NULL pointer, there's no way for the function to notify the caller of the error. Therefore, it's incumbent upon the caller to check before calling.

### No need for separate variable definition and initialization

Do:

```
int res = 0;
int sign = 0;
```

Don't:

```
int res;
int sign;
res = 0;
sign = 1;
```

### Don't reinvent the wheel

Your first loop that skips over whitespace could use the standard library function `isspace()`:

**Edit**: spot the bug in my original code... :/

```
Buggy (oops): while (isspace(*ato++));
Correct:      while (isspace(*ato)) ato++;
```

The condition check in the second loop can use the stdlib function `isdigit()`:

```
while (isdigit(*ato)) {
    ...
    ato++;
}
```

If your instructor or assignment instructions prevent you from using `isspace()` and `isdigit()`, why not go ahead and define them yourself? You already have the logic!<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup> Except you have a minor bug in your check for space characters. You also need to check for vertical tab (`\v`).

**Edit:** Chux points out that calling `isspace(*ato)` and `isdigit(*ato)` when `*ato < 0` invokes undefined behavior (UB). Specifically, the C11 standard, section 7.4, Character Handling, states,

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which **shall be representable as an `unsigned char`** or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

The correct usage, then, of the `isspace()` and `isdigit()` functions in this code would be:

```
while (isspace(*(unsigned char *)ato)) { atoi++; }
//...
while (isdigit(*(unsigned char *)ato)) {
    //...
    ato++;
}
```

Chux also pointed out that your original code as written *did not* have this problem; you weren't invoking undefined behavior. Moral of the story: be careful of the advice you receive from strangers on the Internet...? =)

---

Other than the issues mentioned, you have a decent implementation!

Comment: It is convenient to be able to set a flag to compile a *debug implementation* where you do check for null pointer and emit a diagnostic (and abort)

Comment: @Hurkyl of course, what you're referring to is the use of `assert()` macro. When you no longer want the heavy debugging instrumentation that `assert()` typically carries along with it, you define `NDEBUG`, and the `assert()` typically gets defined out with something like, `#define assert(ignore)((void) 0)`. Note that `NDEBUG` is not specified by C or C++ standards (although most compilers provide for it in their standard library).

Comment: Actually, the C standard does specify that `NDEBUG` is used in that fashion (e.g. in a c11 draft, the section titled `7.2 Diagnostics <assert.h>`)

Comment: @Hurkyl TIL. It's there plain as day. Not only C11, it was also in C99. I could have sworn I searched for it before and concluded it was *referenced* in a sample `<assert.h>` in the standard, but never *specified*. Thanks for the correction, good to know.

Comment: `isspace(*ato)` is UB when `*ato < 0`.  Op's white-space (though incomplete) is not UB.  Same for `isdigit()`.

Comment: If one could use `isspace` and `isdigit` from a standard library, why not use the standard `atoi` and do `int my_atoi(const char *s) { return atoi(s); }` ...?

Comment: @CiaPan in my answer, I said, "If your instructor or assignment instructions prevent you from using `isspace()` and `isdigit()`, why not go ahead and define them yourself? You already have the logic!"

Comment: I'd argue against the use of isdigit() entirely here because at best it obfuscates the code but can never be more correct than testing for the range '0'...'9' directly. The calculation in the loop relies critically on the char to be in this range, thus testing for this range should also be the condition of the loop.

Comment: @x4u you have a good point, but I take slight issue with your choice of wording for "obfuscates". "Abstracts"? Sure. But `while (isdigit(*ato))` is just about as *literate* as you can get for literate programming. I don't think there's much obfuscation going on there. And the testing of the range *is* the condition of the loop, by way of the range returned by `isdigit()`.

Comment: @scottbb Such abstraction is very useful, especially when we need portability. There is no problem with digits, as far as I know, recall, however, there are encodings (e.g. EBCDIC) where alphabet does not make a continuous block. In such encodings `'a' <= c && c <= 'z'` is not necessarily equivalent to `islower(c)`...

Answer (score 6):

Overall, I think this is a really good straightforward implementation, which means it's easy to read and understand. Nice work! I only have a few minor things I'd suggest:

## Don't Reinvent the Wheel (Even When Reinventing the Wheel!)

There's a function to tell if something is whitespace. It's called [`isspace()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm). Your first loop could be rewritten as:

```
while (isspace(*ato))
    ato++;
```

## Use `const` where appropriate

The argument to your function shouldn't be changed (at least from the perspective of someone calling it). As such, it should be marked as `const`:

```
int my_atoi(const char* ato)
```

<strike>Note that this will mean you'll have to copy it and have an extra local variable. But the trade-off in readability and in the ability to reason about the function is worth it.</strike> Now when developers who are using your function see the prototype, they'll immediately know that the value is not changed by the function.

**EDIT**: As usual, I forgot my `const` rules. `const type*` means that the thing pointed to by the pointer is constant, not that the pointer itself is constant. So forget what I said above. You can just use `const char*` and not copy the pointer.

## Naming

I would also clarify the names of variable. They're not terrible, but they could be better. Rather than `res`, why not at least `result`? Or better yet, something like `numeric_value` or something more descriptive? Likewise `ato` does not really tell me what it is. Maybe something like `string_value` or `strVal` at least. (In my opinion, the name of the library function is terrible, too. I didn't know it existed for the longest time because it's so poorly named.)

Other than that, this is pretty decent, in my opinion.

Comment: Crap, didn't notice you beat me to the punch! =)

Comment: No worries! You definitely caught some things I didn't. :-)

Comment: I don't think that making the argument `const` would require copying it to a local variable.  You can still move the pointer.  You just can't write to it.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I always forget that `const` when used with pointers as above means the data pointed to is constant, not that the pointer is. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: If you wanted to make `ato` itself const, it'd be `const char* const` instead — or even `char* const` if you wanted to change the pointee but not the pointer.

Comment: `isspace(*ato)` is UB when `*ato < 0`. OP's white-space test (though incomplete) is not UB.

Comment: If one could use `isspace` from a standard library, why not use the standard `atoi` and do `int my_atoi(const char *s) { return atoi(s); }` ...?

Comment: @chux Can you clarify? I'm not familiar with the acronym "UB".

Comment: Undefined behavior - anything can happen  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 4):

1. **Avoidable integer overflow**.
   When the text version for `INT_MIN` is passed, what happens?  Both `res * 10 + *ato - '0'` and `sign * res` are experiencing `int` overflow, which is undefined behavior.  This means, even if you get the hoped for result today, you may not get it tomorrow or on another complier/platform.  Best to avoid.
   One method is to accumulate `res` amongst the negative side as there is the same or usually more negative numbers than positive one.  (think +2147483647 vs. -2147483648).

   ```
   sign = *ato;  // simple save candidate sign character
   if (*ato == '-' || *ato == '+') {
     ato++;
   }
   while (isdigit(*ato)) {
     res = res * 10 - (*ato - '0');  // -
     ato++;
   }
   if (sign != '-') }
     res = -res;
   }
   return res;
   ```
2. **Unavoidable out of range**.
   `atoi()` has "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."  Your `my_atoi()` could do better by preventing overflow.  A simple method is to use a wider integer type.  Of course that does not help if there is no wider type.  If interested in code that prevents that without a wider type, let me know, as it is not technically needed, your function could have UB too if it is like `atoi()`.
3. **Proper use of `is...()`**
   Recommend use of `isspace()`.  The list of charcters used in OP's code lacks the standard `'\v'` and other spaces characters that are locale dependable,  `is...()` functions are curious in that they are defined for `unsigned char` values and `EOF`.  Avoid `char ch; is....(ch);` if `ch` may have a negative value.  Similar idea for `isdigit()`.

   ```
   // while (*ato == ' ' || *ato == '\t' || *ato == '\n' || *ato == '\f' || *ato == '\r')
   // while (isspace(*ato))   // UB the *ato < 0
   while (isspace((unsigned char) *ato))
   ```

**Minor**

4. No need to declare until the variable is needed.

   ```
   // int res;
   // res = 0;
   int res = 0;
   ```
5. Note that this `my_atoi()`, like `atoi()`, does not define the result of `my_atoi("")`, `my_atoi("xyz")`, `my_atoi("123xyz")`.
6. Note that handling `my_atoi(NULL)` is not needed, if like `atoi()`, as `NULL` is not a valid argument.  It is popular to check for this though.

Comment: Should be `res * -10`? To make the entire value negative

Comment: @Smac89  No - still should be `res * 10 - (*ato - '0')`.  It is still base 10, not base -10.  `res` at that point is negative (or zero).

Comment: If one could use `isdigit` from a standard library, why not use the standard `atoi` and do `int my_atoi(const char *s) { return atoi(s); }` ...?

Comment: @CiaPan Interesting point, or use `(int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`?  IAC, it is an exercise and the typical implications are that such trivial substitutions are not allowed.  But to your point, code should then call/implement `my_isspace()`.

Comment: @chux Yes – and that's what OP, julekgwa, tried to do, performing explicit comparision to a space, tab, newline.. characters.

Comment: @CiaPan Detail: Difference between OP's code and my comment is to call a function such as `my_isspace()` to create a uniformity amongst  `my_...()` functions instead of hard coding in `my_atoi()`.  Should OP not want to use `isspace()` which suffers/benefits from locale differences, then using a stand-alone `my_isspace()` allows for uniformity amongst the rest of code as certainly white-space testing is not needed only in `my_atoi()`.